# MySQL count rows where a=b and b=a

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the first time I've asked a question. It's the first time I've not been able to find what I'm looking for on SO and I think I'm going mad because it should be simple!

Suppose you have a MySQL table, 'T' with two columns 'A', 'B'.

```
A B
---
1 2
2 1
1 3
3 1
2 4
```

I'd like to count mutual relations given a variable. So if I supply

```
X = 1
```

It should return

```
2
```

Because 1, 2 AND 2, 1 exist, and 1, 3 AND 3, 1 exist. However, supply

```
X = 2
```

It should return

```
1
```

Because 1, 2 AND 2, 1 exists, but no other rows where 2 = n AND n = 2.

I hope this is clear! And apologies if it's simple, feel like I'm on a brain freeze..
Cheers!

Comment: What is `X` based on? `A` or `B`??

Comment: @Neal is right. What are you trying to actually solve here? As of now, X does not have a clear relationship to you table based on your question.

Comment: Please see chosen answer. Thanks for your time tho guys. Please let me know if you'd like me to update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work (but if you have a row with (n,n) it will also count as a mutual relation):

```
select count(*) from T t1
join T t2 on t1.B = t2.A
where t1.A = ? and t2.B = ?
```

(pass the same value in for both parameters)

Comment: Just to clarify, counting n,n as a mutual relation would be impossible, as this could never occur in this scenario. I'm new to SO - let me know if I should update the question! Thanks again.